# Strange call of an object method

Tags: javascript, callback, zip

I'm trying to understand how zip.js works

Executing the following code:

```
zipFs.importHttpContent("ptova.zip", false, function() {

 firstEntry = zipFs.root.children[0];

 console.log(firstEntry);

 firstEntry.getText(function(a) {
    console.log(a);
 });

 }, onerror);
```

I can see the text of the first file inside the zip.

But when I go to see how the function is defined I see that:

```
ZipFileEntryProto.getText = function(onend, onprogress, checkCrc32, encoding) {
    this.getData(new TextWriter(encoding), onend, onprogress, checkCrc32);
};
```

So It seems that to call this method I've to pass the "onend, onprogress, checkCrc32, encoding" parameters, but intead they pass a function.

I went to the API webpage and I've seen that this is a callback API Webpage:
http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/fs-api.html

But I don't understand how it's possible to pass another parameters intead of the parameters that the method needs!

Thank you in advance!!

PD: also the .getData method only need one parameter, this one is called "callback"

Comment: JavaScript doesn't require you to pass all the parameters to a function. The ones you leave out will just be `undefined`.

Comment: And witch one is passing with "function(a)", the first one?

Comment: The parameters fill in from left to right, so you gave `onend`.